# Replacing a table row via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dom

I have having issue replacing a row of a table. I am trying to remove the row then append the new row via a rails partial to the table. the new row is appended, but the old row does not get removed. I am able to remove the item if the other row is not added, but I believe that when functions are chained together they happen in the order they are attached in. The original row and the replacement have the same ID which is what i believe is causing the issue, however being that one should be removed before the other is appended I did think there would be an issue.

```
$('#userList')
.remove('#user_<%= @new_user.id %>')
.append("<%=j render :partial=> 'user', :locals => {:user => @new_user, :current_user => @user} %>");
```

Comment: Having the same id shouldn't matter, assuming the new one is being created with the .append() method.

Comment: Without the append method the row is removed

Comment: ... that doesn't make sense... the element you're targeting isn't in the set of selected elements.

Comment: The reason I was targeting it this way was to target the tbody(#userList) and remove the row from it, then add the row back to it with new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you want to remove is a child of `#userlist`, not a sibling. You're going to have to navigate to it.

```
$('#userList').find('#user_<%= @new_user.id %>').remove()
    .end().append("<%=j render :partial=> 'user', :locals => {:user => @new_user, :current_user => @user} %>");
```

But it would make more sense to select it directly.

```
$('#user_<%= @new_user.id %>').remove();
$('#userList').append("<%=j render :partial=> 'user', :locals => {:user => @new_user, :current_user => @user} %>");
```

Comment: This does not remove the row and I end up with two rows with the same id

Comment: This code works, There was other javascript with was failing causing the operations to stop

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is trying to remove #user_* from the set of a SINGLE matched element #userList. You need to just do

```
$('#user_<%= @new_user.id %>').remove();
```

**Fiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KMzCg/

Comment: This will remove the row IF I do not append another row

Comment: Will there only ever be one tr/row?